# real-analysis Limit property question

Tags: real-analysis

$\text{Here is a question that I have been given, }$
$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=A \iff $for each $c\in\mathbb R,\lim_{x\to a-c}f(x+c)=A$.

For this question the proof follows:

$\text{ Proof: Assume } \lim_{\theta\to a}f(x)=A;
 \
\\\forall\epsilon\gt0,\exists\delta\gt0,\forall{\theta}\in\mathbb R, 0\lt | \theta-a| \lt\delta\implies\ |f(x)-A|\lt\epsilon.\\ \text{Given }\epsilon\gt0, \\\text{If$\;$ }     0\lt\; |\theta-(a-c)| \lt\ \delta, \text{choose$\;$ } \theta=x-c,$
$
 $\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{Then$\;$}     0\lt\; |\theta-(a-c)| \lt\ \delta,  & = |\theta-(a-c)| \lt\ \delta \\
& =|(x-c)-(a-c)| \lt\ \delta \\
& =|x-a| \lt\ \delta\\
& \implies\ |f(x)-A|\lt\epsilon\\&\implies\lim_{\theta\to a-c}f(x+c)=A
\end{split}
\end{equation}

$\text{$\therefore$ }$
$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=A \iff $for each $c\in\mathbb R,\lim_{x\to a-c}f(x+c)=A$.

Prove or disprove: Now this one I have tried similar method's with no success.I can't figure what $\theta$ should be in this example.

$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=A \iff $for each $c\neq0,\lim_{x\to a/c}f(cx)=A$.

Comment: Hi, please show us what you have done.

Comment: I have tried many variation changing the variable theta around with theta=a/c, I have tried c*theta=a and tried to solve, c=a/theta etc. It took me forever to input what I have since I am new to LaTex. I will work on entering in my scratch work on the second one so far

Answer (score -1):

You can easily solve your problem by applying the theorem stated by Pedro Tamaroff in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456029/change-of-variables-in-limits). Roughly speaking, you change variable: $cx=u$, and remark that $u \to a$ whenever $x \to a/c$. All this seems rather obvious, but it isn't.

Comment: I have tried many variation changing the variable theta around with theta=a/c, I have tried c*theta=a and tried to solve, c=a/theta etc. It took me forever to input what I have since I am new to LaTex. I will work on entering in my scratch work on the second one so far