# If $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=L$ then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(a_n)=f(L)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

If we have for example $a_n=1+\sqrt{a_{n-1}}$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=L$ then can I say that $ L=1+\sqrt{L}$? If it's so, what's the proof?

Comment: Don't you mean $a_n=1+\sqrt{a_{n-1}}$?

Comment: Yes, if $\lim a_n$ exists, then you can use operations like square root, addition, multiplication

Comment: @vrugtehagel corrected

Comment: As long as $f$ is continuous this is always true.

Comment: If the limit of $a_n$ exists and $f$ is continuous, yes.

Comment: Continuity of the square root function is the reason.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Could you provide a demostration if it's possible? thanks!

Comment: It is enough to suppose $f$ is continuous in $L=\lim a_n$ and $f(a_n)$ is defined for all sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: @JellyBelly It's not completely trivial proof to write down, but it's a very standard theorem in any elementary calculus book.  I'm sure you can find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous and $a_n$ a converging sequence, then $$f(\lim a_n)=\lim f(a_n)$$ Since $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous, and your sequence bounded, yes, you can say $$\lim a_n=\lim a_{n+1}=\lim (1+\sqrt{a_n})=1+\sqrt{\lim a_n}$$
Thus, $$\lim a_n=\frac 32 + \frac 12\sqrt{5}$$

Comment: To say that $f(\lim a_n)=\lim f(a_n)$ which concept/theorem are you using?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588458/for-a-continuous-function-f-and-a-convergent-sequence-x-n-lim-n-rightarro)

Comment: @JellyBelly It is actually a *definition* of being continuous at $L$. However, you might use another definition (that would be equivalent). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_functions).

Comment: Wow! Than you very much! Now it's clear! ^^

Comment: @JellyBelly Perhaps it is worth adding caveat that from this we can calculate the limit $L$, assuming the sequence converges. Although in this particular case, for the function $f(x)=1+\sqrt x$, this sequence will converge for any choice of $a_1$. But, for example, if you look at $f(x)=x^2$ and $a_1=2$, then the sequence given by $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ clearly does not converge neither to $0$ nor to $1$, which are the only solutions of $f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, yes you can, since for such recursive definitions limits are fixed points of the function relating a_n to a_{n-1} (as long as it is continuous).

Comment: thanks for answering, why to be continous is determinant?

Comment: Mainly so we can say that $f(\lim a_n)=\lim f(a_n)=\lim a_{n+1}$. Exchanging the limit and the function can only be done in the case of continuous functions.