# Limits to solve for equation of line

Tags: geometry, limits, functions

If $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} f(x)=3$, $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^-}\ f(x)=3$ and $\ f(0)=5,f'(x)<0$ for x belonging to (-inf,0) and $\ f'(x)>0$ for x belonging to (0,Inf) , then the LINE $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\ f(\cos^3x-\cos^2x) = x \lim\limits_{x \to 0}\ f(\sin^2x-\sin^3x)$  is ?

PS, can that x on RHS be taken inside the limit, even if that wouldnt help in this case?

Comment: HINT: $lim_{x\to0}(\cos^3x-\cos^2x)=0$ and $lim_{x\to0}(\sin^2x-\sin^3x)=0$.

Comment: But that would make the equation 0. The equation is supposed to be of a line

Comment: The line equation turns out to be $3=3x$. See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456029/change-of-variables-in-limits

Comment: since cos^3x-cos^2x is less that zero always, the function on LHS tends to zero only from left. And the function on right tends to zero only from right. So the limit x->0^- must be for LHS and 0^+ for the function on RHS. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that's right, but both limits are equal to 3, so in practice that is not so relevant.